# change in input with angular 2 dynamic detection

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a textbox which act as a search text box. I would like to update the search on text change. This is what I tried with:

```
<input id="searchTextField" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (change)="SearchTextChange()" />
```

and the typescript backend code

```
private SearchTextChange(): void
{
//dostuff
}
```

problem is this only gets triggered off when I click somewhere outside of textbox.
It doesn't gets triggered off when on the change of text.
Why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this should work for you

```
[(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="SearchTextChange()"
```

Comment: what is the difference  between ngModelChange and change? just curious. is it because ngModelChange based on backend model change?

Comment: `change` is HtmlElement event while `ngModelChange` is `@Output EventEmitter` that is firing on `input` and `blur` event